# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ExecuteBatch() on PreparedStatement

Tags: mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm adding 483 objects to a database with preparedStatements and ExecuteBatch().
When I run this code, all the objects are correctly added to the database but after a while the program throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 484
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.processMultiCountsAndKeys(StatementImpl.java:1417)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executePreparedBatchAsMultiStatement(PreparedStatement.java:1515)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1389)
at model.database.SQLCommand.insertMeasurements(SQLCommand.java:110)
at model.database.SQLCommand.addDatasetToDb(SQLCommand.java:31)
at tests.readText.main(readText.java:35)
```

Here is my code:

```
private static List<Long> insertMeasurements(List<Measurement> measurements, long did) throws SQLException {

        conn.setAutoCommit(false);

        List<Long> mids = new ArrayList<Long>();

        String sql = "INSERT INTO doses (CPS, ground, total) VALUES (?, ?, ?);" + " " +
                     "INSERT INTO places (x, y, z, speed) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);" + " " +
                     "INSERT INTO measurements (time, place, note, dose, id_dataset) VALUES (?, (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM places), ?, (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM doses), ?)";

        try (
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS); 
            ) {

            for(Measurement measurement: measurements) {

                ps.clearParameters();
                double cps = measurement.getDose().getCps();
                double ground = measurement.getDose().getGround();
                double total = measurement.getDose().getTotal();

                ps.setDouble(1, cps);
                ps.setDouble(2, ground);
                ps.setDouble(3, total);

                double x = measurement.getPlace().getX();
                double y = measurement.getPlace().getY();
                double z = measurement.getPlace().getZ();
                double speed = measurement.getPlace().getSpeed();

                ps.setDouble(4, x);
                ps.setDouble(5, y);
                ps.setDouble(6, z);
                ps.setDouble(7, speed);

                String time = measurement.getDate().toString();
                String note = measurement.getNote().toString();

                ps.setString(8, time);
                ps.setString(9, note);
                ps.setObject(10, did);

                ps.addBatch();
            }

            ps.executeBatch();
            conn.commit();

            ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
            while (rs.next()) {
             long id = rs.getLong(1);
             mids.add(id);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new SQLException("Can't add the measurement."+e.toString()+"\n" );
        }

        return mids;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like a bug, make sure you are using the latest Connector/J driver and otherwise report to MySQL. Note however that although the MySQL driver supports it, executing multiple statements as one is 'officially' not allowed by the JDBC standard, and the implementation in Connector/J is slightly hacky. You might just hit a corner case of that when you execute them as a batch (as batches are rewritten by MySQL Connector/J to multiple statements, and having multiple statements rewritten as multiple statements might be just a tad too much ;)

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to execute my multiple statements separately? I don't see another way to access the generated primary keys.

Comment: Normally I'd suggest to use the JDBC generated keys facility, but drivers are not required to implement that for batch executions (and most of them don't iirc).

Comment: I'll try to make 3 separate batchs and use the generated keys facility on each of them to provide the keys to the last batch? Thanks for you time :)

Comment: this  exactly looks like a bug and exists even after 4 years (2018) :-( . I just have to end up with a try catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)

Comment: I was getting the same error in Oracle with odbc7.jar, i upgraded to odbc8.jar and the problem has been solved. It looks like the bug was fixed